# How to check real number conditions in an exponential density function? How do I know if I am also asked to calculate a conditional probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

### The exercise

A continuous random variable X, expresses in minutes, the duration of the telephone communications. Its density function is as follows: $f(x)=ke^{-\alpha x}$ if $x>0$, else $f(x)=0$

- a) What conditions must the real $α$ and $k$ verify to be a density function?

If $k=5/6$:

- b) Get the distribution function of X.
- c) Calculates the probability that a communication will last more than three minutes.
- d) Calculates the probability that a communication will last more than five minutes, if it is known to have lasted more than two minutes.

### My doubts

- I know what conditions have to meet a density function. But in part (a), how should I analyze these two real numbers? Is it with limits? If so, how should I evaluate them?
- In part (d), should I interpret it as a conditional probability? If so, in what way can I calculate it?

*If you have more to say about the rest of the exercise, you are also welcome. Thank you very much.*

Comment: The conditions that a density function have to meet will give you restrictions on $k$ and $\alpha$. For (d), you can interpret it as a conditional probability, for which you'll need to derive a conditional density. You might discover an interesting property of the exponential distribution in the process.

Comment: @Theoretical Economist Yes, but part (a) I'm doing it by observation (using my calculator). I wanted to know if it could be done in a more direct way. In part (d), could you explain a little more about the conditional probability for this point case?

Answer (score 1):

(a) You want, $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$, and $\int_\Bbb R f(x)\operatorname d x=1$.   So what constraints on $k, \alpha$ make this possible?

(b) $\mathsf P(X\leq b) = \int_{-\infty}^b f(x)\operatorname d x$

(c) $\mathsf P(X>b) = \int_b^\infty f(x)\operatorname d x$

(d) You want $\mathsf P(X > 5\mid X > 2)$, so use Bayes' Rule and the above.

---

Tip: $\int_b^c e^{-ax} \operatorname d x = \tfrac 1a(e^{-ab}-e^{-ac})$

Comment: I did the calculations and they gave me $\displaystyle\alpha=\dfrac{5}{6}$ and $\displaystyle F_X(x)=1-e^{-\dfrac{5}{6}x}$. Is there any way to verify if what I did was okay?

Comment: @AccomOuter Verified: What you did was okay.