# How is the Bayes theorem expressed by integrals?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

I need to apply Bayes' theorem for a conditional probability which in turn makes use of continuous random variables.

**Context:** *A continuous random variable $X$, expresses in minutes, the duration of the telephone communications. Its density function is as follows: if $x>0$ $\Rightarrow f(x)=(5/6)ℯ^{-(5/6)x}$*

- I have $F_X(x) = 1-ℯ^{-(5/6)x}$
- I need to calculate $\mathsf P(X>5\mid X>2)$

**How can I express $\displaystyle P(A_i|B) = \frac{P(B|A_i) P(A_i)}{\sum_{k=1}^n P(B|A_k) P(A_k)}.... [1]$ through integrals?**

If you like to contribute something more about the [exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2143407/408375), it is also welcome. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$ \Pr(X>5\mid X>2) = \frac{\Pr(X>5,X>2)}{\Pr(X>2)} = \frac{\Pr(X>5)}{\Pr(X>2)} = \frac{1-F_X(5)}{1-F_X(2)}.$$

Comment: That's because if $A$ the call lasts for more than 5 minutes then $B$ has lasted for more than 2 minutes, so $A→B\Rightarrow A \subseteq B \Rightarrow A\cap B=A$. Or why is it?

Comment: Yes you are right. $\{\omega:X(\omega)>5\} \cap \{\omega:X(\omega)>2\} = \{\omega:X(\omega)>5\}.$